# Regular Expression problem

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for javascript that will get "`jones.com/ca`" from "`Hello we are jones.com/ca in Tampa`". The "`jones.com/ca`" could be any web url extension (example: .net, .co, .gov, etc), and any name. So the regular expression needs to find all instances of say "`.com`" and all the text to the last white space or beginning of line and to the last white space or end of line (minus any ending punctuation).

Right now I have as an example line: "`jones.com/ca some text`", using a javascript regular expression of: "`\\(.+?^\\s).com?([^\\s]+)?\\`", and all I get is "`.com/ca`" as the output.

Comment: "any web url extension", if you mean a valid TLD, is a *very* long list. Much longer than just .com .net .co and .gov. May be best to match something that looks like it might be a TLD.

Comment: You need to let me know how detailed you expect the regex to be and I can edit my post. I am actually the Joe that posted the last scratched out regex at this link http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/archive/2005/12/01/61722.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This example will capture specific domains com,org and gov

```
\b\w+\.(?:com|org|gov)/[a-z]{2}\b
```

And this will capture almost any domain

```
\b\w+\.[a-z]{2,3}/[a-z]{2}\b
```

It uses word boundaries so that it does not capture white space.

Answer (score 0):

Matching URLs is a bit of a dark art. The following site has a fairly well-designed regex for this purpose: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive regex for this is going to be much more complicated than you think. The [list of top-level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) is fairly long (.gov, .info, .edu, .museum, etc.), and there are "special" domains like localhost as well. Also, many domains end in a two-letter country abbreviation (google.com.br for Google Brazil, for example, or del.icio.us).

The easiest thing would be to look for `http(s)://` or `www` at the beginning and just assume what comes after is a domain name. If you don't, you're going to either miss a lot, or get a lot of false positives.

You could try the following, but the last option (after the last `|`) is going to be open to a significant number of false positives:

```
/https?:\/\/\S+|www\.\S+|([-a-z0-9_]+\.)+(com|org|edu|gov|mil|info|[a-z]{2})(\/\S*)?|([-a-z0-9_]+\.)+[-a-z0-9_]+\/\S*/ig
```